# Android equivalent of iOS's dispatch_after

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c

Or any other mechanism to delay code execution without hanging the main thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `Handler`'s `postDelayed()`. [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long))

Answer (score 1):

Java example

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //logic
    }
}, 2000);
```

or

```
Thread({
    try{
        Thread.sleep(2000)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        //
    }
    //logic
}).start()
```